# Why does Mutex instantiation throw System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException when I use a path for the name parameter?

Tags: .net, mutex

When I do this:

```
using (Mutex MyMutex = new Mutex(true, Environment.CurrentDirectory))
{

}
```

A `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException` is thrown.  I see other questions on here addressing how to avoid that which is to replace `\` with something else like `.` or `-`, but I want to know *why* it's doing that.  Why is it try to resolve the mutex name as a path?  It doesn't try to resolve `asdf` as a path.  What is going on here?

Comment: Are you sure you want to build a `Mutex` based on `Environment.CurrentDirectory`? That sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @Luaan I am creating a logger that uses a mutex to place an interprocess lock a file.  I want to use the file name and path as the name since it's guaranteed to be unique.  I am aware that this lock won't be honored by applications not acquiring the mutex.  Edit:  I used `Environment.CurrentDirectory` just for an example.  I am not actually using that in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mutex is created within a store called the ObjectDirectory, all Mutex keys are actually paths within this store.  The fact that you've given an absolute path, means the implementation will try to resolve that.  Take a read of the win32 document here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: To resolve, obviously just replace / with another character such as    space or string.empty